# R version of inplace=True

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I'm starting to learn R and I'm having a hard time making changes to the names of values in a factor. I've tried using revalue and recode but am still seeing the original names when I look at the dataframe.

Here's what the DF looks like:

```
head(freecut)

  gender oldness student_loaniness homeland
1      0      20                 4  Eurasia
2      1      25                 4   Oceana
3      1      56                 2 Eastasia
4      0      65                 6 Eastasia
5      1      50                 5   Oceana
6      0      20                 5 Eastasia
```

And here are the coding attempts:

```
revalue(freecut$homeland, c("Eastasia" = "East_Asia", "Eurasia" = "Asiope",
   "Oceana" = "Nemoville"))

recode(freecut$homeland, Eastasia = "East_Asia", Eurasia = "Asiope", 
   Oceana = "Nemoville")
```

After running the code the DF looks exactly the same. I know that in Python I would have to throw in "inplace = TRUE" to make changes stick--not sure what I need to do here (or what I'm missing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R doesn't modify in place, you have to assign results - either back to the original variable to modify it, or to a new variable. This is a paradigm of *functional programming*, and R is a functional programming language.

If you have `x = 1`, running `x + 1` will evaluate and print the result, `2`, but `x` is not changed. If you want to overwrite `x` with the modified value, you run `x = x + 1`.

Just the same way, running `recode`, will evaluate and print a result, but if you want to modify the column in your data frame, you need to explicitly assign it with `freecut$homeland = recode(...)`.

---

There are a few exceptions in add-on packages. For example, the `data.table` package defines some `set*` operators which do modify objects in place. `data.table` is fantastic, especially if you need efficiency, but if you are just starting with R I would recommend getting familiar with the basics first.

Comment: (Not important but... ) Even with `:=` you need to refer to the target on the LHS, `x := f(x)`, though `setattr` does modify in place: `x = factor("a"); setattr(x, "levels", "b"); x` (though much less safely than recode, relevel or whatever). There's also `x %<>% f` in magrittr; `levels(x) <- y`, others.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gregor's answer which addresses more fundamental issues, you can in your particular case use `levels<-`:

```
levels(freecut$homeland) <- c("first", "second", "third")
# order is important if you don't want surprises
```

Or if you are ready to join the dark side, consider macros from `gtools` package. The first steps are described e.g. in https://www.r-bloggers.com/macros-in-r/. Nobody is using macros in R but I don't know why. Maybe they're dangerous but maybe they just seem obscure.